# Determine the convergence of the sequence $ a_{n}=\tan (\frac{6n \pi}{7+24n}) $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

Determine the convergence of the sequence $ a_{n}=\tan (\frac{6n \pi}{7+24n}) $  . Also find the the limit.

**Answer:** $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } a_{n} = \tan (\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{6 \pi}{7/n+24})=\tan (\frac{\pi}{4} )=1 $ . So the sequence converges to 1. **Am I right ?**

Comment: The difference between your *solution* and @MichaelRozenberg 's answer is rigor.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is right, but your way is not so right. You need to add some words.

Right words are:

Since $\tan$ is a continuous function on $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, we obtain:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\tan\frac{6\pi n}{7+24n}=\tan\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{6\pi}{\frac{7}{n}+24}=\tan\frac{\pi}{4}=1.$$
So the sequence converges to $1$.